# get url from http.get() response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to give my program 3 URLs than print out the server responses in the order of given URLs.
I need a way to see from which URL the response came, but I can't find any solution in the documentation. Is there something like "response.getURL" out there?
Thanks in advance.

```
var strings = [];
var ended = 0;
for(int i=0; i<urls.length; i++){
    http.get(urls[i], function(response){
        var wholeData = "";
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('error', console.error);
        response.on('data', function(data){
            wholeData += data;
        });
        response.on('end', function(){
            ended ++;
            strings[???] = data;
            if(ended == urls.length)
                printStrings();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single URL for an `http.get()`: `urls[i]`.

The `response` will correspond to that `urls[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign `strings[i] = wholeData` you'll have to change how you loop because the value of `i` inside that event handler will equal `urls.length`. You could use a library like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) which would avoid your having to keep a request counter around and such, but if you want to keep your existing code you need to use a closure around your `http.get()` to capture `i` or just use `urls.forEach()`:

```
urls.forEach(function(url, i) {
  http.get(url, function(response){
    var wholeData = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('error', console.error);
    response.on('data', function(data){
      wholeData += data;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
      ++ended;
      strings[i] = wholeData;
      if (ended === urls.length)
        printStrings();
    });
  });
});
```

Or you could group your results by url instead of array index by making `strings` an object and doing `strings[url] = wholeData` instead.

Comment: The exercise didn't permit using async libraries. I wrapped an extra function in the for loop, so index didn't get lost and it worked well.
Thanks for the help.